# how to load images in gridview from other location

Tags: android

I follow this [tutorial](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/)
 below is my code which load images from application internal  memory and display using simple adapter but now i want to ad checkbox i found this tutorial which llad images from gallery i want to customize this sample code to load image from file location what do i do how do i change this code to load image from file location or how to customize its adapter to load my files what do i do help plz

```
               <!-----------------this is my code------>
 GridView gridView;
 SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter;

    gridView =(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int  
                        position,long id) {


        if(currentFiles[position].isDirectory())
        {
            root = new File("/data/data/com.myexample/files 
                /"+FileName(currentFilePath[position])+"/");

            Log.e("Root first",root+ " ");

            currentFiles = root.listFiles();

            inflateListView(currentFiles);
        }
        else if(currentFiles[position].isFile())
        {
                   inflateListView(currentFiles);
        } } });

         private void inflateListView(File[] files){

  List<Map<String,Object>> listItems = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();

 for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++)
 {      
        Map<String, Object> listItem = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        if(files[i].isDirectory())
        {
            listItem.put("icon", R.drawable.folder);
        }
        else
        {
            listItem.put("icon",  files[i]);
        }

        listItem.put("fileName", files[i].getName());
        listItems.add(listItem);
    }

      simpleAdapter=new SimpleAdapter(this,listItems,R.layout.line,new String[] 
      {"icon","fileName"},new int[]{R.id.icon,R.id.file_name});
      gridView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);




       <!--------this is sample code--------->>>>>>


import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class AndroidCustomGalleryActivity extends Activity {
private int count;
private Bitmap[] thumbnails;
private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
private String[] arrPath;
private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, 
     MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
    Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, 
       null,
            null, orderBy);
    int image_column_index =  
       imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
    this.thumbnails = new Bitmap[this.count];
    this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
    this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        int dataColumnIndex = 
    imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
        arrPath[i]= imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
    }
    GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
    imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    imagecursor.close();

    final Button selectBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectBtn);
    selectBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final int len = thumbnailsselection.length;
            int cnt = 0;
            String selectImages = "";
            for (int i =0; i<len; i++)
            {
                if (thumbnailsselection[i]){
                    cnt++;
                    selectImages = selectImages + arrPath[i] + 
    "|";
                }
            }
            if (cnt == 0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please select at least one image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "You've selected Total " + cnt +  
  "  
       image(s).",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("SelectedImages", selectImages);
            }
        }
    });
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ImageAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
         getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.galleryitem, null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView)  
        convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox)  
       convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.checkbox.setId(position);
        holder.imageview.setId(position);
        holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                int id = cb.getId();
                if (thumbnailsselection[id]){
                    cb.setChecked(false);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                } else {
                    cb.setChecked(true);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                }
            }
        });
        holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int id = v.getId();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + 
    arrPath[id]), "image/*");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnails[position]);
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
        holder.id = position;
        return convertView;
    }
}
class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageview;
    CheckBox checkbox;
    int id;
}
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import com.example.appsecurity.AndroidCustomGalleryActivity.ImageAdapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class unhide extends Activity {
    private int count;
    private Bitmap[] thumbnails;
    private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
    private String[] arrPath;
   private ImageAdapter imageAdapter1 ;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.unhide);

        final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};

        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;

        Cursor imagecursor = getContentResolver().query( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                columns, 
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
                new String[] {"%/./%"},  
                null);
                int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);          
                this.count = imagecursor.getCount();        
                this.thumbnails = new Bitmap[this.count];       
                this.arrPath = new String[this.count];  
                this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];

        for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {

            imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);

            int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);        
            int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA); 

          thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(        
                    getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,       
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);     

            arrPath[i]= imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);





    }

        GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.Unhide);      
        ImageAdapter  imageAdapter1  =  ImageAdapter();      
        imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter1);     
        imagecursor.close();
}
    private ImageAdapter ImageAdapter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```